# Tester indicates hot/ground are reversed after lightning strike

Tags: electrical

Another post-lightning strike problem:  we have a run of outlets that no longer make a connection when you touch black & white wires, yet get a connection when touching black to the ground wire with a multimeter.  A circuit tester reads "Hot/Ground Reversed."  The outlet at the end of the run is totally dead.  PLUS, we just upgraded the service TODAY and we are still having the problem, so it's not at the breaker.  This was not an issue before the lightning strike. Ever heard of such a thing?

The wire coming out of the panel is a 3-wire bx. The circuit that the black wire feeds is just fine, yet the circuit the red wire feeds gives us the reverse/ground reading. I know that can be an open neutral, but if both hot wires are coming from the same cable, shouldn't both show the open problem? Any idea what could be going on? We get the bad reading at the first junction box after the panel, on the red wire coming from the panel.

Comment: We're testing circuits because none of the outlets work anymore and when we tested the wiring, we got the Hot/Ground Reversed reading.  Can a GFCI getting fried cause the polarity to change?

Comment: What kind of tester are you using (including model number)? I don't see how any tester would be able to detect a reversed hot/ground when connected only to the hot and ground -- are you sure it didn't say "Hot/Neutral reversed"? In any case, unless all 3 contacts are connected (hot+neutral+ground), an outlet tester may not give reliable results.

Comment: We're using a "SNAPIT Correct" circuit tester.  Plus, we're using a Southwire 10030S multimeter which has no reading when touching black & white, but reads 120v when touching black & ground.  I know, it's a really strange thing. Had an electrician here today & he's never seen anything like it.

Comment: The information about the multimeter test would be good to put into your original question, sounds like you have an open neutral. If the strike was bad enough to sever a neutral connection, I think this is the point where you call in a professional electrician to evaluate the entire house.

Comment: Took your advice. Edited the original question.

Comment: Yeah, definitely an open neutral *somewhere* -- is it just this circuit that lost the outlets? Part of a circuit? Or several circuits?  Also, is there a GFCI or AFCI anywhere on the circuit?

Comment: It is one circuit with 4 GFCIs along the run.  It's the only circuit we're having problems with.

Comment: Do any of the GFCIs work? Are they all daisy-chained or independent?

Comment: They are a mix of daisy-chained & independent & it appears all are shot.

Comment: Our open/reverse ground since the lightening strike has still not been resolved, but we're getting closer.

The wire coming out of the panel is a 3-wire bx. The circuit that the black wire feeds is just fine, yet the circuit the red wire feeds gives us the reverse/ground reading. I know that can be an open neutral, but if both hot wires are coming from the same cable, shouldn't both show the open problem? Any idea what could be going on? We get the bad reading at the first junction box after the panel, on the red wire coming from the panel.

Thanks.

Comment: Are the red and black wires coming from the same leg or opposite legs of your service?

Comment: Showing my novice-ness, I'm not sure what you mean by same/opposite leg.  Both red & black come out of the same bx cable, but each is connected to a different breaker.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere in your house wiring a neutral line is disconnected / broken / melted. You will need to open every electrical box and check the connections and splices. If you don't find anything there, do continuity tests between junction boxes. If the fault is between boxes you may need to open the walls up.

Your GFCI outlets are almost certainly dead. Any overcurrent big enough to sever a wire will fry a GFCI. Just replace the lot.

"Hot/Ground Reversed" isn't testable without a third connection. There should be full voltage between hot and ground - if not then you have an open ground. If you put a meter between ground and a known-good ground (like a metal water pipe) and see full voltage then you really do have hot and ground reversed (and a major problem - call an electrician).

Comment: Most 3-lamp testers will show "Hot/Ground reversed" if the neutral's open.

Comment: Yes.  Because any load on the circuit will pull neutral toward 120V, so it looks to the tester like there's 120V between neutral and ground.

Comment: ANOTHER QUESTION:  We've been trying to trace this crazy maze of wires, but still haven't been able to sort it out.  In the trace, I found a bx cable that seems to be caved in.  The cable is at an end of the run & that outlet was the only one that was totally dead (the others all showed reversed ground.)  Can a squished bx go bad out of nowhere, when it's been there since, probably, the 60s or 70s?  And could it cause the reversed ground on the rest, even tho it's the end of the line?

Comment: UPDATE:  Looks like the squished cable was the culprit.  We took it out of the circuit & everything works again.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I found the GFI receptacle was bad and the "hot/ground reversed" was fixed after replacing the GFI receptacle.

Comment: Yeah, that'd be consistent with the GFCI not resetting properly (leaving the neutral open)